# Installing Ubuntu, how do I get it to recognize the Crucial RealSSD C300?

Tags: ubuntu, install, ssd

I'm building a new rig and got the RealSSD C300 for its supposedly stellar performance, but it is not recognized when I try to install Ubuntu 10.4LTS 64-bit.  Is there anything that I can do to get this recognized?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question lies in the SATA3 controller. This forum thread answers the question.

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1456238

In summary, in the BIOS change the SATA3 controller mode to AHCI, this should allow linux to find and use the drive.

Answer (score 0):

Is it recognized by the BIOS? Does it work with a Windows Live-CD? According to e.g. [this page](http://hardwarelogic.com/articles.php?id=10992&page=6) or [this blog post in German](http://kefk.org/node/55214) it should just work with Ubuntu 10.4.

Comment: Recognized by both CMOS and Windows install disk.

Comment: could it be the SATA 3 that it is connected to?